# Why are these messages in the Eclipse console?

Tags: java, eclipse, osgi

I have lots of messages for various bundles in the plugins directory that look like the one below when I run my OSGi application.  How do I prevent this from happening?

> ```
> !ENTRY org.eclipse.update.configurator 4 0 2013-10-11 17:53:24.417
> !MESSAGE Could not install bundle plugins/com.sun.el_2.2.0.v201303151357.jar   Bundle "com.sun.el"
> ```
>
> version "2.2.0.v201303151357" has already been installed from:
>   reference:file:/Applications/eclipse-4.3/plugins/com.sun.el_2.2.0.v201303151357.jar

I found from searches that I should add the following line to config.ini

```
org.eclipse.update.reconcile=false
```

But it's already in there, see my file below:

**/Applications/eclipse-4.3/configuration:**

```
#This configuration file was written by: org.eclipse.equinox.internal.frameworkadmin.equinox.EquinoxFwConfigFileParser
#Fri Oct 11 17:46:42 IST 2013
org.eclipse.update.reconcile=false
eclipse.p2.profile=epp.package.standard
osgi.instance.area.default=@user.home/Documents/workspace
osgi.framework=file\:plugins/org.eclipse.osgi_3.9.1.v20130814-1242.jar
equinox.use.ds=true
eclipse.buildId=4.3.0.M20130911-1000
osgi.bundles=reference\:file\:org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator_1.0.400.v20130327-2119.jar@1\:start
org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator.configUrl=file\:org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator/bundles.info
eclipse.product=org.eclipse.platform.ide
osgi.splashPath=platform\:/base/plugins/org.eclipse.platform
osgi.framework.extensions=
eclipse.p2.data.area=@config.dir/../p2/
eclipse.application=org.eclipse.ui.ide.workbench
osgi.bundles.defaultStartLevel=4
```

Comment: I'm having the same problem! But i wasn't!!! Don't know what changed... Did you resolve the issue? How?

Comment: Found an answer to this yet? I'm having the same issue with Eclipse.